# How to get selected value from mysql to dropdown list?

Tags: php, mysql, dropdown

I have question about dropdown list in php using mysql to populate it.
I'll try to describe it as clear as possible.

First, the tables

```
|              Cars            |      |      Colors       |
--------------------------------      ---------------------
|car_id|     name   | color_id |      |color_id|color_name|
--------------------------------      ---------------------
| 01   |   BMW      |   c1     |      |  c1    |  Silver  |
| 02   |   Audi     |   c2     |      |  c2    |  Black   |
| 03   | Chevrolet  |   c3     |      |  c3    |  White   |
```

I already create form to input a car data to `cars` table. In that form i create a dropdown list to get `color_name`,
and there was no problem to save it. The problem is how to get selected `color_name` on update form using dropdown?

Comment: "The problem is how to get selected color_name on update form using dropdown?" Can you explain this please.

Comment: @DhiwaTdg i mean, how show color_name to dropdown based on color_id in cars table.

Comment: is your question related to the sql thing or is it the HTML part?

Comment: You already have a dropdown with list of color-names and you want to change it based on what color you receive from the db. Is that what you want?

Comment: @jossif the HTML part

Comment: @DhiwaTdG yes.. thats it.. sorry for my bad english...

Comment: That's alright. Check the answer. Let me know if it doesn't help.

Answer (score 4):

If selected_color is the color what you got from DB. Then use the following code to set your drop down list.

```
$("#dropDownList").val(selected_color);
```

Comment: is there anyway to use pure php? i don't have much jquery knowledge..

Comment: How do you want to change the dropdown value. Is it while loading the page or in ajax?

Comment: see my answer, which handles the server side. however, DhiwaTdG's answer is pretty useful as well.

Comment: @DhiwaTdG, i will choose ajax if i have enough knowledge, but right know  i'll use php

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you're looking for...

```
                            <select name="color" id="color">
                            <?php do { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $row['color_id'] ?>" <?php if (!(strcmp($row['color_id'], $row_rsEdit['color_id']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>><?php echo $row['color_name'] ?></option>
                            <?php } while ($row = $rsColors->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)); ?>
                            </select>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try your code too..

Answer (score 0):

Is it that you're looking for?

```
<select>
  <option selected>Silver</option>
  <option>Black</option>
</select>
```

In order to get that dynamically, do something like this:

```
<select>
  <?php foreach($colors as $color): ?>
     <option <?php echo ($color == $theActualSelectedColor) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>><?php echo $color ?></option>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

This is simplified. You may wanna use the color IDs as the option's values instead and just output the color names in the visible part of the dropdown.

Comment: thank you. I'll try ur code